# Code is not executing after window.load (Javascript)

Tags: events, loops, dom, window.open

*(sorry for my bad english)*

I have a big problem with which I've been beating me for several days but to which I do not find any solution, even while going to excavate very far in subjects on known forums (and less known).
I develop a small application in Javascript which must recover an array of links. I open these links one by one in the same page, and I click on a button (which posts a name), then I check after a small lapse of time that the name is well posted and corresponds to that present on the page (in a fixed div). At this time, I turn over on the basic page, then I start the script again with the second link contained in the array.

The problem is that the code is not carried out anymore after the window.load() function.
I test the code on Google Chrome (in the Javascript console) and it turns over me an error: “Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined … onload ".

I hope that you will be able to help me to find how to once carry out the code with the launching of the page it is launched since each bond opens a page in the relationship page.
Before, I had tested in a popup with the function window.open () (without “_parent”) and I wanted to close it thanks to window.close () function, but the code did not include/understand where to act since the remainder of the code was to now deal with the popup and not of the page on which the code was carried out at the beginning.

Here's the code :

```
//Here i get the links in an array
    function recupHref(){
        var lesHref = new Array();
        var lesLiens = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

        for(var i = 0; i < lesLiens.length; i ++)
            if(lesLiens[i].parentNode.getAttribute("class") == "pubrhead-text-right")
                lesHref.push(lesLiens[i].getAttribute("href"));
        return lesHref;
    }
    var resultat = recupHref(); //I store them in a variable

//The main function which open the links one by one
//The while loop allows us to know if were subscribed or not 
    var o = function openLinks(){

        for(var leIndex = 0; leIndex < resultat.length; leIndex ++){
            window.open(resultat[leIndex], "_parent");

              //Do i use window.load instead of DOMContentLoaded ?
        addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            document.getElementById("enbut").click();
            var pseudo = document.getElementById("nameho").innerHTML;
            var pseudok = document.getElementsByClassName("pname")[0].textContent;
        });

        while (pseudo === pseudok) {
            !(window.open("http://page-with-links.html", "_parent"));
        };
    }
}
```

I thank you in advance, and I hope that you will include/understand my problem.

Here is a little draw to explain better than words :
[image: Little schema]

In other words, just what i need is that : store links (done) --> Open the link --> Click on the button (done) --> Check if the 2 names are the same --> Came back to the first page/close popup/ (or go directly to the seconde link in the array) --> do this for the 2nd link, etc, etc.

Good day/evening.

Comment: Nobody knows how to do it ?